# How to test in app purchases in Flutter [IAP][testing]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, testing, in-app-purchase

I'm using the official [in_app_purchase package](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) from Google, but I can't find any information on how to test IAP in Flutter after it's set up.

Android and iOS have their own guides, but they require you to add libraries and code manually which is not compatible with the way Flutter auto-generates native code.

Is there a "right" way of testing in app purchases in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

To test in app purchases, follow instructions from [Google Code Labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#4)

> To be able to test in-app purchases, Google accounts of your testers
> must be added in the Google Play console in two locations:
>
> - To the specific test track (Internal testing)
> - As a license tester

Once you configure yourself as a "license tester" you can test different scenarios using "License response" drop down (see image below).

[image: Adding License testers]